# Unable to retrieve metadata for 'JMAP.Models.tempSource'. Keyword not supported 'data source'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Visual studio 2010 and EntityFramework version 5.0.0.0
I am trying to create a controller for a 'tempSource' table in Oracle 11.2 and getting the following error.
[image]

This is the code for the entity.

namespace JMAP.Models
{

```
public class tempSource
{               
    public string systemname { get; set; }
    public string systemdesc { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
}

public class tempSourceDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<tempSource> tempSources { get; set; }
}
```

}

add name="tempSourceDBContext" 
connectionString="User Id=user_id;Password=pwd;DATASOURCE=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = portnumber))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = dbname)))"

providerName="System.Data.OracleCLient"

And I have added the above connection string in the web.config file.

Can someone help me with this error.

Comment: I am getting a new error today "Unable to retrieve metadata for'JMAP.Models..Class1'. A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on a store provider instance of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection'. The store provider might not be functining correctly."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was my bad! I was following a wrong approach. I was using the  code-first approach whereas I wanted to use Data-first approach,but being new to MVC and C# , I just got confused.

If someone needs help with MVC and is a beginner like me, you can go through the following website for databse design approaches. Pretty useful.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views

Moreover, you can also go through these videos, a bit time consuming, but it gives you an understanding of MVC.

https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc-8322

Hope it helps!